# MacOsX: ScreenSaver -- how to get the path to .saver bundle

Tags: macos, cocoa, screensaver

I have a ScreenSaver project. In the Resources of this project presents the image file.
I'm trying to load it like this:

```
NSString* imageName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DefaultImage" ofType:@"jpg"];
mpCurrentImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imageName];
```

But the path of mainBundle is
/Applications/System Preferences.app/Contents/Resources

How to get the path to the .saver bundle, to load the image from recourses?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd want to use

```
NSString* imageName = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:@"DefaultImage" ofType:@"jpg"];
```

assuming that this code is in a class belonging to the bundle.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for silly question) I use objective-c and cocoa not so long time...